# Android DatePicker like Android Calendar app

Tags: android, layout, view, android-datepicker

I am trying to implement an activity where I want the user to put a date information.

I would like it to look like the Android Calendar App. Their button looks like a spinner, but with the selected date (picture 1). When the button is clicked, it opens the Date Picker dialog (picture 2).

http://pineapple.cc/datepicker1.png

http://pineapple.cc/datepicker2.png

Should I use a redesigned button, spinner, textview ?

Thank you a lot for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Does the [supplied widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) not do it for you?</s> Ooops misunderstood question. Disregard.

Edit:

I'm looking at the [EditEventView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/calendar/event/EditEventView.java?av=h) activity in the Calendar app, and they're using a button that launches the DatePicker widget. The setDate() method there does the formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not able to find out how they configure their button to have the little grey triangle on the bottom right part ?

Comment: That's just a style with a background resource. You can extend it with your own button style by adding: 

parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner" 

 to the custom style in xml.